# MySQL joins and COUNT(*) from another table

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join, having

I have two tables: `groups` and `group_members`.

The `groups` table contains all the information for each group, such as its ID, title, description, etc.

In the `group_members` table, it lists all the members who are apart of each group like this:

```
group_id | user_id
1 | 100
2 | 23
2 | 100
9 | 601
```

Basically, I want to list THREE groups on a page, and I only want to list groups which have MORE than four members.  Inside the `<?php while ?>` loop, I then want to four members who are apart of that group. I'm having no trouble listing the groups, and listing the members in another internal loop, I just cannot refine the groups so that ONLY those with more than 4 members show.

Does anybody know how to do this? I'm sure it's with MySQL joins.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

MySQL use [HAVING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) statement for this tasks.

Your query would look like this:

```
SELECT g.group_id, COUNT(m.member_id) AS members
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN group_members AS m USING(group_id)
GROUP BY g.group_id
HAVING members > 4
```

example when references have different names

```
SELECT g.id, COUNT(m.member_id) AS members
FROM groups AS g
LEFT JOIN group_members AS m ON g.id = m.group_id
GROUP BY g.id
HAVING members > 4
```

Also, make sure that you set indexes inside your database schema for keys you are using in JOINS as it can affect your site performance.

Comment: I altered the SQL to fit my code: `SELECT g.id, COUNT(m.id_profile) AS members
FROM groups_main AS g
                LEFT JOIN groups_fans AS m USING(id)
                GROUP BY g.id
HAVING members > 4`
Results in this MySQL error: "Unknown column 'id' in 'from clause'.

Comment: You can use USING statement in only if two columns carry same name, in other cases use ON statement I would update my answer.

Answer (score 63):

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.id, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM group_members
        WHERE member_id = groups.id) AS memberCount
FROM groups
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. This helped me to achieve what I was trying to do.

Comment: This helped me in a query I was struggling with. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this useful trick. I helps me a lot. I was used as find in set function.

Comment: Although subqueries are not performance friendly in mysql, this is quick good solution comes handy when performance is not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am off the mark here and not understanding the OP but why are you joining tables?

If you have a table with members and this table has a column named "group_id", you can just run a query on the members table to get a count of the members grouped by the group_id.

```
SELECT group_id, COUNT(*) as membercount 
FROM members 
GROUP BY group_id 
HAVING membercount > 4
```

This should have the least overhead simply because you are avoiding a join but should still give you what you wanted.

If you want the group details and description etc, then add a join from the members table back to the groups table to retrieve the name would give you the quickest result.

Answer (score 1):

Your `groups_main` table has a key column named `id`. I believe you can only use the `USING` syntax for the join if the `groups_fans` table has a key column with the same name, which it probably does not. So instead, try this:

`LEFT JOIN groups_fans AS m ON m.group_id = g.id`

Or replace `group_id` with whatever the appropriate column name is in the `groups_fans` table.