# For each SQL result, another SQL query? in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count

I need help at getting data from MySQL Database. Right now I have a query that gives me:

**Tournament ID**

**Tournament Name**

**Tournament Entry fee**

**Tournament Start and End date**

For tournaments I am registered in. **Now I want, for each tournament I am registered in, to count how many users are in that tournament, my points in that tournament**, etc.

That info is in table called **'ladder'**

**ladder.id**

**ladder.points**

**ladder.userFK**

**ladder.tournamentFK**

Database: http://prntscr.com/99fju1

PHP CODE for displaying tournaments I am registered in:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$sql = "SELECT distinct tournaments.idtournament, tournaments.name, tournaments.entryfee, tournaments.start, tournaments.end
                from tournaments join ladder
                on tournaments.idtournament= ladder.tournamentFK and ladder.userFK=".$_SESSION['userid']."
                group by tournaments.idtournament";

$result = $conn->query($sql);               
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {                      
            $tournament="<li class='registered' data-id=".$row['idtournament']." data-entryfee=".$row['entryfee']." data-prize=".$tournamentPrize."><span class='name'>".$row['name']."</span><span class='entry-fee'>Entry fee: ".$row['entryfee']."&euro;</span><span class='prize-pool'>Prize pool: &euro;</span><span class='date-end'>".$row['start']."-".$row['end']."</span><span class='btns'><button>Standings</button></span></li>";
            echo $tournament;
        }                   
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: So, What **OUTPUT** you expect ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, for each tournament I would like to count how many users are in that tournament, dont know how to do it in PHP. Do I make a query within a while statement? @NanaPartykar

Comment: Edit with your exact table schema and you will get answer easy.

Comment: Database model added. @AnandSingh

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can combine JOIN, COUNT() and GROUP BY in your query.

Some examples:
[MySQL joins and COUNT(*) from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847089/mysql-joins-and-count-from-another-table)

Answer (score 0):

This would be the query I think.Change column and table name if its not correct. **Not tested** but I am sure this will give you some idea to make required query

```
select count(ladder.tournamentId)as userCount,tournaments.name 
    from 
     ladder left join tournaments 
      on ladder.tournamentId =  tournaments.id 
       where ladder.tournamentId in 
         (
         select tournaments.id from 
           tournaments left join ladder 
            on ladder.tournamentId =  tournaments.id 
             where  ladder.userId='yourId'
          ) and ladder.userId <> 'yourId'
            group by ladder.tournamentId
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but it does not work the way I want to. I think what I want to achieve can not be done in a single SQL query, it needs PHP approach, and thats what im looking to find here