# Have duplicate field in other table mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables :

games:
game_id int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
archive_moves   varchar(3000)   NO
chat    varchar(3000)   NO

players:
player_id   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
username    varchar(30) NO  UNI
password    varchar(30) NO
email   varchar(30) NO  UNI
activate    bit(1)  NO      b'0'
hash    varchar(32) NO
game_number int(10) NO  MUL 0

playersgames:
playergame_id   int(11) NO  PRI     auto_increment
player_id   int(11) NO  MUL
game_id int(11) NO  MUL
game_number int(10) NO  MUL 0

playersgames.game_id is foreign key for games.game_id
playersgames.player_id is foreign key for player.player_id

What I want is game_number gets exactly the same value from players to playersgames. So I created a foreign key between players.game_number and playersgames.game_number and "cascade on update" it.
The problem is when I change value from players.game_number, the value for playersgames gets the highest value from players.game_number and there is no more connection between players.player_id and his player.game_number.

The idea behind this is to get playersgames.player_id only if game_number < 5. In other words, a player cannot has more than 5 games. I'm open to other solution if it's more convenient.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `game_number` column in your `playergames` table or in the `players` table. Instead you can run the following query:

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    COUNT(g.playergame_id) AS numGames
FROM
    players p
LEFT JOIN
    playersgames g ON p.player_id = g.player_id
GROUP BY
    p.player_id
```

The result will give you the player ids and the number of games the player has. See also: [MySQL joins and COUNT(*) from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4847089/mysql-joins-and-count-from-another-table).

Comment: Thanks, I totally forget the count method. Here is my final request : "SELECT player_id FROM players WHERE player_id NOT IN (SELECT player_id FROM (SELECT player_id, COUNT(playergame_id) AS numGames, game_id FROM playersgames GROUP BY player_id) AS S1 WHERE game_id IN(SELECT game_id FROM playersgames WHERE player_id=7) OR numGames > 5) LIMIT 1;". I use it for create a matchmaking between players. Conditions are : max 5 games per player and only one match for peer of two players.
Thanks a lot again !!!